# sql update from R when some columns are of type Text

Tags: sql, sql-server, r, etl

I am trying to append a SQL table (Target_SqlTable) based on the data I have in a dataframe (Source_DataFrame1).

The Source_DataFrame1 has around 30 columns and few of these columns are free text columns with large volume of free text data.

On the SQL Db side these columns are defined as text

When I try to use

```
sqlSave(myconn,Source_DataFrame1,"Target_SqlTable",append=TRUE, rownames=FALSE, colnames = FALSE, safer=FALSE,  verbose = TRUE)
```

to update the Target_SqlTable with this data from the Source_DataFrame1 in R It dosent go through.

This fails because of those columns that are of type text and not the default varchar. So how do i update a table in SQL through R by specifying custom column types where few columns are of type Text ?

For the sake of example lets assume that I have dataframe with 10 columns and column 2, 4, 6 are of type Text. So question is how do I specify that these columns are of type Text when I update the SQL table from R ? Any help is much appreciated folks.

Answer (score 0):

`sqlSave` has an option called `typeInfo` where you can declare how to convert `R` data types. `typeInfo` is in the form of a list such as:

```
colspec <- list(character="mediumtext", double="double",
                integer="integer", logical="varchar(5)")
```

`mediumtext` is the data type used within `MySQL` in this example.

You havent mentioned which flavour of SQL you are using so the above is just an example.

Following that you are then able to declare this list as the data types to be used within `sqlSave`:

```
sqlSave(myconn,Source_DataFrame1,"Target_SqlTable",append=TRUE,
        rownames=FALSE, colnames = FALSE, safer=FALSE,
        verbose = TRUE, typeInfo=colspec)
```

See https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RODBC/RODBC.pdf for further details.